# has_many or join - what's the 'rails way' to use my table?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database that keeps track of accidents. Each accident can have multiple causes. Each cause has a friendly name in a 3rd table. What's the 'rails way' to create this association?

Here's what I have:

```
create_table "accidents", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "notes"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "causes", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "accident_id"
  t.integer  "cause_name_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "cause_names", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
CauseName.create :name => "DUI"
CauseName.create :name => "Speeding"
```

Accident:

```
class Accident ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :causes
end
```

Causes:

```
class Cause < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accidents
  has_one :cause_name
end
```

cause names:

```
class CauseName < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :causes
end
```

It seems like to be properly "ORM"'d, I'd use it like this:

```
Accident.causes.first.cause_name.name #speeding
a = CauseName.find(1)
Accident.causes.first.cause_name = a #set and saved successfully
```

I've been trying a variety of things, but I can't seem to get my associations to work the way I'd expect. I know I'm not using it right.

I'm very new to rails and activerecord, and horrible with databases... the schema I'm working with was designed by our dba who will be doing reporting on the table, but knows nothing about Ruby or ActiveRecord.

What's the best approach in my situation? Am I even using this thing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your `belongs_to` and `has_one` methods placed incorrectly in your `Cause - CauseName` association.

Quoting the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one):

> If you want to set up a one-to-one relationship between two models,
>   you'll need to add belongs_to to one, and has_one to the other. How do
>   you know which is which?
>
> **The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the
>   table for the class declaring the belongs_to association)**, but you
>   should give some thought to the actual meaning of the data as well.
>   The has_one relationship says that one of something is yours - that
>   is, that something points back to you.

So, in your case, it should be like this:

```
class CauseName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cause # Note that I have changed :causes to singular too
end

class Cause < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accident # <- Singularized too
  belongs_to :cause_name
end
```

Comment: That's exactly where I went wrong. Also, it's important to remember to use the singular reference when using has_one and belongs_to, something I had mistaken. I'm surprised that ActiveRecord didn't bark at me when I made this mistake. I'm unsure if it's because it fixed it for me, or because it failed silently. Odd.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I'd suggest not splitting causes into two tables. Just cram `name` into causes table and call it a day.

Then you can easily query like `@accident.causes.first.name`

Comment: Part of the reason we broke it out in the first place is to maintain the ability to tweak the cause_names slightly over time. For instance, we might go from "Speeding" to "Speeding - Motorcycle" and add "speeding - car". Obviously, in a real world example we'd add another column entirely for automobile_type, but you get the general idea. Is it poor design to just save the plain language string "speeding"/"DUI" in the table? seems like it wouldn't be  scalable? What's your opinion?

Comment: You're right. If you want to manage names of the causes, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. Don't forget to add indexes to foreign keys and `name`.